# error in /opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros/stack.xml

Tags: roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

After updating ros fuerte today, I had the problem, that /opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros/stack.xml contained multiple "author" tags, which made roslaunch fail unconditional. Did anyone see this before?

Best Georg

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/37836/error-in-/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros/stack.xml/) by [Georg](https://answers.ros.org/users/171/georg/) on ROS Answers with karma: 328 on 2012-07-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Duplicate of [update-fuerte-to-1810-breaks-rospkg](http://answers.ros.org/question/37397/update-fuerte-to-1810-breaks-rospkg/) and [problem-with-roscore](http://answers.ros.org/question/37697/problem-with-roscore/).

There's a good description of how to cleanup easy_install pip installs at: http://answers.ros.org/question/49143/problems-with-rqt-groovy-ubuntu/?answer=49153#post-id-49153

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2012-07-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) on 2012-07-03**:
...This really needs to be fixed...

**Comment by [Georg](https://answers.ros.org/users/171/georg/) on 2012-07-03**:
Thanks for the hint, but what should one do now? How can i remove the "old" style install of rospkg?

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-07-03**:
`sudo pip install -U rospkg` will fix it as the answers suggest. Currently, there is no other clean way. Doing a `sudo pip uninstall rospkg` works, too, but when you update rosdep using pip, it will be pulled in again.